# How can I round the corners on multiple InDesign frames?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am doing a photo collage layout as part of a re-creation of some older creative for a client. I'm rounding the corners in InDesign by clicking the yellow box below the upper-right handle and then dragging the corners to around `5p0`. This is exactly what I'm looking for, but I want to know if there is a shortcut to apply the same effect to all 20+ photos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the frames and adjust the corner options in the **Control Bar**.

[image]

Or, select all the frames and choose `Object > Corner Options`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could also define an object style and apply it to your frames. This would make it easier to change the corners later on. If you have multiple pages you can't select all frames at once.

Answer (score 1):

- Using the selection tool, select all photos
- Choose Object > Corner
- Options Choose a corner effect and specify the preferred size for one or all corners

Done